# Spring Data Rest : how to send Multi-part file with request Body

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, multipartform-data

I want to construct an API of user signup in which I need user basic information and his/her profile picture also so I am very confuse that how can I achieve this ! I have made a controller and requested for a body But When I access this API it gives me error of `"Unsupported Media Type"` and when I set content Type as `multipart/form-data` then it gives an error of : 
`the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found`

Please help How can I send user information and user photo BOTH in SAME request

**UPDATED : Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "createRider")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> createRider(
        @RequestBody CreateRider createRider,Authentication authentication,
        PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler,@RequestPart(value = "profilePic", required = false) MultipartFile file) {

    if (authentication != null && authentication.getPrincipal() != null) {
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
        boolean authorized = authorities.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("rights"));
        if (authorized==true)
            userService.createNewRider(createRider);
        else
            return  ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.SC_CONFLICT).body("Logged In user is not admin");
    } else {
        // Access denied
        throw new AccessDeniedException("Not logged in");
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Rider Created");
}
```

**createRider.java**

```
public class CreateRider {

    private String email;

    private String name;

    private String password;

    private String contactNumber;

    private String cnicNumber;

    private String drivingLicense;

    private String reference;

    private MultipartFile file;
     ..getters nad setters 
    }
```

**userService.createNewRider**

```
public void createNewRider(CreateRider createRider) {
        Group group=groupRepo.findOne(Constants.RIDER_USER_GROUP);
        User user=new User();
        user.setGroup(group);
        user.setEmail(createRider.getEmail());
        user.setName(createRider.getName());
        user.setPassword(createRider.getPassword());
        user.setContactNumber(createRider.getContactNumber());
        user.setCnicNumber(createRider.getCnicNumber());
        user.setDrivingLicense(createRider.getDrivingLicense());
        user.setReference(createRider.getReference());
        userRepo.save(user);
        RiderLocation riderLocation=new RiderLocation();
        riderLocation.setRider(user);
        riderLocationRepo.save(riderLocation);
        ///User Photo 
         UserPhoto userPhoto=photoService.createUserPhoto(createRider.getFile(), user.getId());
         userPhotoRepo.save(userPhoto);



    }
```

Comment: If you've  solved would you please share your solution

Answer (score 0):

You can get the profile picture as a [MultipartFile](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html) by adding the following to the controller

`@RequestPart(value = "profilePic", required = false)  MultipartFile profilePic`

So the controller method becomes

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestPart;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "createRider")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> createRider(
        @RequestPart CreateRider createRider,Authentication authentication,
        PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler, @RequestPart(value = "profilePic", required = false)  MultipartFile profilePic) {

}
```

Comment: and what about  requestBody createRider ?

Comment: `@RequestBody CreateRider createRider `



I also want other information name , password etc

Comment: That you can load using @RequestPart, as mentioned in the answer

Comment: Okay wait let me try

Comment: How can I send data from postman ? And what should be the content-type?

Comment: set key as `file` under form data for uploading files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147236/discussion-between-sfah-and-jobin).